# Failing to open the app in a specific view controller after taping in a local notification

Tags: ios, swift

I have this app with the fallowing View Hierarchy:

HOME

```
UINavigationController
    MainViewController
        UINavigationController
            DashboardController
                YTPageController
                    DashboardInitialViewController
```

USERS

```
UINavigationController
    UsersViewController
```

ADD USERS

```
UINavigationController
    AddUsersViewController
```

From `HOME` you can `show segue` to `USERS`, and from `USERS` you can `show segue` to `ADD USERS`

I want to be able to tap a local notification and go directly to `ADD USERS`, no matter where I am in the app.

If I'm in `HOME`, there is no problem.

The problem is where I'm in `USERS` and I tap in the notification. Nothing happens.

I have try to remove `USERS` FROM the View Hierarchy but nothing seems to happen.

This is the code that executes when I tap in the notification:

```
if  let conversationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddUsersViewController") as? AddUsersViewController {

     if var navController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
          navController.isNavigationBarHidden = true                   
          navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
          navController.pushViewController(conversationVC, animated: true)
     }
}
```

I have try in the other navigation controller in `HOME`, but also nothing.

```
if  let conversationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddUsersViewController") as? AddUsersViewController {

    if var navController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

         if let main = navController.viewControllers[0] as? UIViewController {
                if let nav = main.navigationController as? UINavigationController {
                     nav.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                     nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                     nav.pushViewController(conversationVC, animated: true)

                  }
        }                      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the animated to false or use the other function with completed and push the viewController in the completed function.
The problem is that the code directly keeps on running and tries to push the new view controller on the other one which isn't popped yet.

```
navController.isNavigationBarHidden = true                   
navController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
navController.pushViewController(conversationVC, animated: true)
```

and...

```
nav.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
nav.pushViewController(conversationVC, animated: true)
```